# Optimal way to store ansible playbook output to the file or database

Tags: shell, ansible

our idea is to use ansible for populating some sort of inventory database with static and dynamic data for dozens different hosts
Som,  for example,  to store  ansible shell command midule  output to the flat file indicating which source node it was recieved from. 
It is noted that Ansible might not be the best tool for doing that as being configuration management tool, but for our case  it would simplify many things

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool called **ansible-cmdb**: https://github.com/fboender/ansible-cmdb

You can customize the output and even add new metrics with ansible [local facts (facts.d)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d). We used it for a simple cmdb and inventory overview. 
It's possible to render a simple html file or populate database with colleted facts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is valuable info, but is there more generic way to  pass output of genric shell script to the flat file or database. It seems that  ansible-cmdb tool can gather only "ansible facts"  data

Comment: You can also use the JSON Callback or YAML Plugin: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/callback/json.html. This will give you all the ansible output as json.